# *ngfor does not show previous objects after adding new object to array

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a new customer form in angular 14 where an *ngFor loop iterates over an objects array. Each object is shown in its own component with its fields as inputs so it could be edited. A button in the parent component can add an empty object to the array.

The Problem is that when new object is added, the values of the previous are not shown in their components although they be seen when logged.

I tried using trackBy which solve the problem, but makes editing difficult as it keeps jumping out of focus for the field used as tracker.

Any help would be appreciated.

Parent component:

```js
export class CreateCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('customerForm') customerForm!: NgForm;
  customer: Customer = {
    companyName: '',
    contactsList: [
      {
        contactEmail: '',
        contactName: '',
      },
    ],
    id: undefined,
    creationDate: undefined,
  };

  addNewContactFields() {
    this.customer.contactsList.push({ contactEmail: '', contactName: '' });
  }

  editContact(contactChangeEvent: { contact: Contact; index: number }) {    
    const contact = this.customer.contactsList[contactChangeEvent.index];
    contact.contactEmail = contactChangeEvent.contact.contactEmail;
    contact.contactName = contactChangeEvent.contact.contactName;
  }

  trackBy(index: number, contact: Contact): string {
    return contact.contactEmail;
  }
```

Parent template:

```html
<form  
  #customerForm="ngForm" 
>
  <ng-container >
    <label for="contactsList">Contacts:</label>
      <div>
        <app-add-contact
          *ngFor="let contact of customer.contactsList; index as i; trackBy: trackBy"
          name="contactsList"
          [index]="i"
          [contact]="contact"
          (changeContactName)="editContact($event)"
          (changeContactEmail)="editContact($event)"
          (deleteContactTask)="removeContactFromList($event)"
        >
        </app-add-contact>
      </div>
    <fa-icon
      [icon]="faCirclePlus"
      (click)="addNewContactFields()"
    >
    </fa-icon>
  </ng-container>
  <app-form-buttons
    [continueButton]="{text:'Save & Create License', isShown: true}"
    [saveButton]="{text:'Save', isShown: true}"
    [customerForm]="customerForm"
    (clickContinue)="onClickContinue()"
    (clickSave)="onClickSave()"
    (clickReturn)="onClickReturn()"
  >
</form>
```

Child component:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}],
})
export class AddContactComponent {
  @Input() index = 0;
  @Input() contact!: Contact;
  @Output() changeContactName = new EventEmitter<{contact: Contact, index: number}>();
  @Output() changeContactEmail = new EventEmitter<{contact: Contact, index: number}>();
  @Output() deleteContactTask = new EventEmitter<number>();
  
  clickCreateContactName(name: string) {
    this.contact.contactName = name;
    this.changeContactName.emit({contact: this.contact, index: this.index});
  }

  clickCreateContactEmail(email: string) {
    this.contact.contactEmail = email;
    this.changeContactEmail.emit({contact: this.contact, index: this.index});
  }

  clickDeleteContact() {
    this.deleteContactTask.emit(this.index);
  }
}
```

Child template:

```html
<fieldset ngModelGroup={{contact.contactEmail}} >
  <div>
    <label for="contactName">Name:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="contactName"
      required
      #name="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="contact.contactName"
      (change)="changeCreateContactName(name.value)"
    >
    <p *ngIf="name.touched && !name.valid">
      Please enter contact name
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="contactEmail">Email:</label>
    <input
      type="email"
      name="contactEmail"
      required
      email
      #email="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="contact.contactEmail"
      (change)="changeCreateContactEmail(email.value)"
    >
    <p *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid">
      Please enter a valid email
    </p>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-phptjj?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
showing the problem. You could use
[Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)
to create one.

Comment: With ChangeDetectionRef you could force component to update

Comment: @O-9 The problem is that object  values are not shown, but I do see the empty object that was added to the array. It looks like it reset the form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that yours inputs have the same "name" property. You can use `[name]="'contactName'+index"`

```
<input
  ...
  [name]="'contactName'+index"
/>
...
<input
  ...
  [name]="'contactEmail'+index"
/>
```

BTW: Liran is unnecesary your contact.component emit values. As you pass an object, the object it's the same (you only has one object) so you can remove the `(change)="changeCreateContactName(name.value)"`. Futhermore, you're using `[(ngModel)]`. This is "two ways binding", when you change the value in the input you change the value in .ts

```
<input
      type="text"
      [name]="'contactName'+i"
      required
      #name="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="contact.contactName"
    />
```

I [forked your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-heatzp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontact%2Fcontact.component.ts) to see that it's all more easy

NOTE: Perhafs it's interesting if you want to use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead use [(ngModel)] -They are a bit complex but more powefull than use [(ngModel)]

Comment: I eventually used reactive forms as you suggested. Although it was very complex with the loop and the child component, I achieved all the functionality I needed. Thank you.